# Filling a new column in a dataframe by calling a calculation

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to calculate the distance between coordinates, so the calculation is quite complicated. I know I can use this to create a new column

```
df['distance'] = calculation    # where calculation is the distance formula between coordinates
```

But how do I define some calculation,  similar to this formula, which recursively fills the distance value after computing it:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) )
d = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth)
```

Do I use def?

Example df:

```
 lat1     long1     lat2      long2
34.43432 134.23423  34.42321 128.23244
34.42132 132.23231  32.32321 140.43213
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function is what you were looking for.

```
def f(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lat1 = abs(radians(lat1))
    lat2 = abs(radians(lat2))
    lon1 = abs(radians(lon1))
    lon2 = abs(radians(lon2))
    
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    d = R * c
    return d

df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.lat1, x.long1, x.lat2, x.long2), axis=1)
```

Instead of building the calculation function yourself, you can also use the [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package:

```
import geopy.distance

df['distance_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: geopy.distance.distance([x.lat1, x.long1], [x.lat2, x.long2]), axis=1)
```